# Python - Extract year and month from a single column of different year and month arrangements

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create two columns "Year" and "Month" from a Date column that contains different year and month arrangements. Some are YY-Mmm and the others are Mmm-YY.

```py
import pandas as pd

dataSet = {
    "Date": ["18-Jan", "18-Jan", "18-Feb", "18-Feb", "Oct-17", "Oct-17"],
    "Quantity": [3476, 20, 789, 409, 81, 640],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dataSet, columns=["Date", "Quantity"])
```

My attempt is as follows:

```py
Date1 = []
Date2 = []
for dt in df.Date:
    Date1.append(dt.split("-")[0])
    Date2.append(dt.split("-")[1])

Year = []
try:
    for yr in Date1:
        Year.append(int(yr.Date1))
except:
    for yr in Date2:
        Year.append(int(yr.Date2))
```

Comment: Variable names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. More importantly, how did you end up in this situation?

Comment: I was given a large dataset as a practice as I'm learning Python. This problem was unintentional and was not meant to be part of the practice, which is for plotting. I tried to come up with my own solution by splitting the date and loop it with try-except as I figure year and month are integer and string, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `extract` dataframe string method to split the date strings up. Since the year can precede or follow the month, we can get a bit creative and have a `Year1` column and `Year2` columns for either position. Then use `np.where` to create a single `Year` column pulls from each of these other year columns.

For example:

```py
import numpy as np

split_dates = df["Date"].str.extract(r"(?P<Year1>\d+)?-?(?P<Month>\w+)-?(?P<Year2>\d+)?")

split_dates["Year"] = np.where(
    split_dates["Year1"].notna(),
    split_dates["Year1"],
    split_dates["Year2"],
)

split_dates = split_dates[["Year", "Month"]]
```

With result for `split_dates`:

```py
  Year Month
0   18   Jan
1   18   Jan
2   18   Feb
3   18   Feb
4   17   Oct
5   17   Oct
```

Then you can merge back with your original dataframe with `pd.merge`, like so:

```py
pd.merge(df, split_dates, how="inner", left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Which yields:

```py
     Date  Quantity Year Month
0  18-Jan      3476   18   Jan
1  18-Jan        20   18   Jan
2  18-Feb       789   18   Feb
3  18-Feb       409   18   Feb
4  Oct-17        81   17   Oct
5  Oct-17       640   17   Oct
```

Comment: Nicely done! I was trying to think of a RegEx, this is a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help. I managed to get it working with what I've learned so far, i.e. for loop, if-else and split() and with the help of another expert.

```
# Split the Date column and store it in an array
dA = []
for dP in df.Date:
    dA.append(dP.split("-"))
# Append month and year to respective lists based on if conditions
Month = []
Year = []
for moYr in dA:
    if len(moYr[0]) == 2:
        Month.append(moYr[1])
        Year.append(moYr[0])
    else:
        Month.append(moYr[0])
        Year.append(moYr[1])
```

This took me hours!

Comment: Congratulations on solving your own problem! Sometimes it takes hours to get to what seems like something so small - but that time is an investment in solving future problems, so take pride in this accomplishment, learn from it, and one day you'll look back, remember this problem, sigh with nostalgia, and think to yourself, "I remember when my problems were so simple they only took hours!" Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Python `datetime strptime(<date>, "%y-%b")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) on the date column to convert it to a Python `datetime`.

```py
from datetime import datetime

def parse_dt(x):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(x, "%y-%b")
    except:
        return datetime.strptime(x, "%b-%y")

df['timestamp'] = df['Date'].apply(parse_dt)

df
     Date  Quantity  timestamp
0  18-Jan      3476 2018-01-01
1  18-Jan        20 2018-01-01
2  18-Feb       789 2018-02-01
3  18-Feb       409 2018-02-01
4  Oct-17        81 2017-10-01
5  Oct-17       640 2017-10-01
```

Then you can just use [`.month`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.month)  and [`.year`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.year)  attributes, or if you prefer the month as its abbreviated form, use [Python `datetime.strftime('%b')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

```
df['year'] = df.timestamp.apply(lambda x: x.year)
df['month'] = df.timestamp.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b'))

df
     Date  Quantity  timestamp  year month
0  18-Jan      3476 2018-01-01  2018   Jan
1  18-Jan        20 2018-01-01  2018   Jan
2  18-Feb       789 2018-02-01  2018   Feb
3  18-Feb       409 2018-02-01  2018   Feb
4  Oct-17        81 2017-10-01  2017   Oct
5  Oct-17       640 2017-10-01  2017   Oct
```